# Acumatica Add Wiki's to Customization

Tags: acumatica

We have added several Wiki Articles to the Acumatica and now trying to add them to Customization Project to be able to setup them on another System. The problem is that when we add Wiki's Page ID( they all are in the HelpRoot_User) it add all the Wiki Pages and Zip's size is becoming 40 MB. When we tried to import that Customization Zip to another System we got`

> File exceeds maximum allowed size (25000 KB).

Has anybody done Wiki's export to Customization?
How can I do this?

Comment: When you say it added all the wiki pages... are you saying it included all standard wiki pages (not just the wikis you need)? We do package wikis. I will need to review are setup before I can help to answer.

Comment: @Brendan yes, exactly

Comment: I would say that is your root problem as you could agree. You should only need to package the wiki's you created. We created a new wiki not attached to any other standard wiki. Let me find out the details and post as an answer.

Comment: added answer. In summary the articles should be self contained into a main wiki. The main wiki is selected in the customization project. Because there is no way to exclude specific articles from the customization project (without possibly editing the project.xml) I would say this is your best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we did to include our wiki in a package. The idea here is to create a new wiki and include all articles under the new custom wiki. When selecting in the customization you will select the new custom wiki. In My Example I called this "HelpCustom"

1. Create a new wiki in CONFIGURATION > DOCUMENT MANAGEMENT > MANAGE > WIKI
   We added the wiki to the main horizontal bar in the help section. You can define where your wiki lives by selecting the location in 'Site Map Location'.
   [image]
2. Find your article in the location you picked in the site map location and add any articles you need.
   [image]
3. In your customization project, under Wikis, click Add (+) and select the Wiki created from step 1.
   [image]

Now the problem you have is how do you transfer the articles to the new wiki so you don't have to redo them. I did a quick test to move an article that was created in a different wiki and here is what I did.

Find the main wiki record in wikipage that you created in step 1 above.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.WikiPage
WHERE [CompanyID] = 2
      AND [Name] = 'HelpCustom';
```

Use the PageID value from the result above as the WikiID and ParentUID in your articles. If you need the articles nested then you will have to adjust the ParentUID to fit (or leave the value as is depending on the row not being at the root of the wiki article tree). I would assume you only need to change the ParentUID value for the top level articles. Otherwise just update WikiID for all articles that need to move.

Here is the script I executed. I could not tell if I needed to update the [Number] column value or not.

```
UPDATE dbo.WikiPage
SET [ParentUID] = 'F1BF807E-4B0E-414C-B90B-83944AC66D8C', /*Use PageID from parent*/
    [WikiID] = 'F1BF807E-4B0E-414C-B90B-83944AC66D8C'     /*Use PageID from main wiki*/
WHERE [CompanyID] = 2
      AND [Name] = 'TESTDEV1'; /*article name*/
```

I had to restart/refresh my site to see the article move to my new wiki.

Hope this gives you some direction.

Comment: I will try this and let you know

Comment: Now I'm getting error like this http://take.ms/cB56x anytime I try to publish WikiCustomization. There is only 1 wiki article in the customization.

Comment: This error seems to be associated with Database and it was solved after optimizing the database

Comment: Seems like this error has not been fixed. I continue getting it almost every time I try to publish customization from Customization Projects

Comment: what if you try to change the key of the wikis that you copied? maybe some type of conflict? What happens if you create a new test article in the wiki as the only article, still an error? Also, after making the changes... did you recycle your website? possible that the ID and/or wiki was cached in some form.

Comment: I have created one for test. I think there is some problem after first publish. Because first one gave me error. Then I unpublished all. I was getting error until I went and manually add and remove all wiki's which must be added.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you hit the 25MB limit default value validated by the import popup window.

That validation error is directly related to file upload functionality rather than Wiki. Try setting a larger upload file limit in 
Acumatica configuration.

Configuration->Document Management->Configure->File Upload Preferences
[image]

Comment: This works for import. But now I'm getting time out when trying to publish the customization

Comment: I'd guess you hit the ASP timeout, the workaround is to increase the execution timeout in the web.config file <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" [...] />

Comment: As @Brendan has written the problem is not the size of zip or timeout by itself. The main problem is to get only wiki pages we modified/added.

Comment: In that case I agree. I thought you simply had to put a lot of data in a single section.

Answer (score 0):

The ParentID is the ID of the folder for an article.  An article may be a folder also and have subarticles under it.  For example:
Form Reference
  Stock Items
  Non-Stock Items